# Why can't we define (assign a value) a variable (field) after it is declared in a class?

Tags: java, class, field

In a normal class,

```
public class MyClass {
    int a =12; 
}
```

works fine.

But,

```
public class MyClass {
    int a =12;
    int b;
    b=13;
}
```

this gives a compilation error.

I know I am trying to access a field without using an object of that class, so I even tried this->

```
public class MyClass {
    int a =12;
    int b;
    MyClass m= new MyClass();
    m.b=13;
}
```

but even this doesn't seem to work.

I can accept the fact that this is how things work and move on. But does anyone know the logic behind this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: put that line into a constructor / method, you are simply not allowed arbitrary statements top level in a class outside a method.

Comment: you can also use a non-static initializer block, if you want to be really fancy about it

Comment: I should have clarified, I am aware of different solutions like using a constructor or using an initializer block as mentioned in the comments above. 

But I am looking for a "Why so?" rather than a solution. 
Thank you anyway.

Comment: tl;dr you can't execute arbitrary code inside the body of a class.

Answer (score 1):

```
int a = 12;
```

This is a variable declaration with initialisation.

```
b=13;
```

This is an assignment; a statement; it cannot be part of the declaration. It has to be part of the constructor or method.

It is how Java object definition works.

- variable/field declarations
- constructors
- methods (static or non-static)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one of the following two ways:

1. Use the initialization block as follows:

   ```
   int b;
   {
       b = 13;
   }
   ```
2. Do the following in the constructor:

   ```
   b = 13;
   ```

Check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html to learn more about it.

Comment: Beware though, that whichever method you choose to assign a value, that you use that method EVERYWHERE in your project. Mixing these kind of things will cause no end of issues when you (or some poor maintenance developer) try to modify your code at some future date. Try to keep confusion to a minimum...